# Computer-Unique Integer

Tags: c#, wmi, guid

I'm trying to look for a unique 32-bit integer that I can access in C#. The integer should be specific to a particular computer; but it doesn't have to be collision resistant.

I've looked at the MAC Address and ProcessorId, but both are too large to store as Int32.
Any other suggestions (other than truncating the aforementioned identifiers to fit)?

Comment: AFAIK any number that you are going to find consistently (on all PCs) that has to pretend to be unique will be too long because they are intended to be collision resistant. 4 bytes is just not realistically long enough to identify anything mass produced.

Comment: I suppose it would be nice if it didn't have to be 32 bits. Is that not an option to change?

Comment: If it doesn't have to be collision resistant why don't you just use 42 for all values?

Comment: I would be very careful about truncating the MAC addresses you might end up with quite a few more collisions.

Comment: This seems to be an odd implementation/request.  What actual requirement are you trying to fulfill?

Comment: Maybe like this: http://xkcd.com/221/ Although it actually returns a 3 bit number..

Comment: Lets be clearer: I wanted something that's going to be unique to each computer the program analyses to store as a database index (which can be later referenced)
In the theoretical 1/4.2 billion event there is a collision, the program can just generate a random number as the ID for a special case. Doing this however means that it may look at the same computer again sometime in the future when the database is queried - which is  not desirable, but fine for odd cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take you MAC address and/or processorID of whatever else you want to use and run it through a hash function that will produce a 32-bit value.

A simple CRC32 would probably do the job, since you aren't concerned about collisions.

If it helps, I found a convenient implementation of CRC32 [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/01/14/free-hash-a-reusable-crc-32-hashalgorithm-implementation-for-net.aspx).

Comment: Good suggestion. You have to be careful about the account running, though, because and admin account will get different hardware ID's than a normal account.

Comment: Hashing: why on earth didn't I think of that. Thanks!